# PyCharm, Discord bot doesn't see any changes

Tags: python, pycharm, discord, bots

I'm making a Disord bot. I have no problems with code, but when I'm trying to change command (it's structure for example) and running the code, it acts like I didn't apply any changes! For example:

```
if message.content.startswith("_hi"):
    await message.channel.send("Hello!")
```

Then I'm changing await message to another:

```
if message content.startswith("_hi"):
    await message.channel.send("Hi there!")
```

And bot responding as the first variant. Why?

The same situation when I'm writing NEW if-message. I think bot literally doesn't see this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your bot hasn't applied the changes yet will be because you haven't restarted the file/bot yet.

I would press `STRG + S` after each change, just to be sure, this "saves" the file, but is not absolutely necessary.

To view changes live you have to restart the bot/file. You can do this by clicking on the `Run` button in the upper right corner.

**This is how it should look like:**

[image]

Here we have first the file of your bot, which should always start and next to it the button to restart the bot/program/file.